# Dokku Buil Failed - Pre-receive hook declined

Tags: node.js, heroku, docker, digital-ocean, dokku

Been trying to figure this out for hours, but I just updated Docker on my server, and now I can't push anything new to it through "git push dokku origin master"

This is the message I get. Please help!!!

```
Counting objects: 59, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (56/56), done.
Writing



objects: 100% (59/59), 5.89 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 59 (delta 38), reused 0 (delta 0)
-----> Cleaning up...
-----> Building psofnyc from herokuish...
-----> Adding BUILD_ENV to build environment...
-----> Node.js app detected

-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true

-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  4.1.2
       engines.npm (package.json):   2.14.4

       Downloading and installing node 4.1.2...
       npm 2.14.4 already installed with node

-----> Restoring cache
       Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
       - node_modules (not cached - skipping)
       - bower_components (not cached - skipping)

-----> Building dependencies
       Pruning any extraneous modules
       Installing node modules (package.json)
remote: /tmp/buildpacks/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/lib/dependencies.sh: line 10:   306 Killed                  npm install --unsafe-perm --userconfig $build_dir/.npmrc 2>&1

-----> Build failed

       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/

       Love,
       Heroku

To dokku@159.203.184.171:psofnyc
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

Answer (score 4):

I suspect it's the `npm install` command that is failing:

- https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/blob/master/lib/dependencies.sh#L21

I'm not a nodejs expert but the "Killed" error suggests it's running out of memory.

Comment: This is definitely the issue, and you will want to at minimum add more swap memory to handle `npm install` runs. This doesn't happen on Heroku as they use a different system from your provisioned dyno to build the slug.